# Android Studio Error "Cannot resolve symbol attachToRoot"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm trying to learn how Fragment works in Android Studio.
I've set a LayoutInflater in my code yet it says that my `attachToRoot: false` cannot be resolved.
Here is my code

```
package com.example.rouletteapptest;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class fragment1 extends Fragment {

    TextView text,vers;

    public fragment1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, attachToRoot:False);
        text = view.findViewById(R.id.AndroidApp);
        vers = view.findViewById(R.id.Description)
        return view;
    }
    public void change(String txt, String txt1){
        text.setText(txt);
        vers.setText(txt1);
    }
}
```

Comment: remove `attachToRoot`

Answer (score 2):

You should change attachToRoot:False to false, like code bellow

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);
```

And I think, you should refactor your class name, cause that's not recommended.
Like from "fragment1" become "FragmentOne"

Answer (score 1):

change

`View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, attachToRoot:False);`

to

`View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);`

Answer (score 0):

just type `False` and then hold <kbd>SPACE</kbd>  it is okay.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).